# Exc_bad_Access after upgrading to Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3

Tags: swift

After upgrading to XCOde 8.3 and iOS 10.3 and my iPhone, my project is not working anymore.

When selecting an annotation on my map, the app crashes and this line is highlighted in the debugger:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
```

The crash log is this one:

```
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           app.TEST.test [1370]

Date/Time:           2017-03-29 11:34:09.4286 +0200
Launch Time:         2017-03-29 11:33:38.3835 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3 (14E277)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000016fc5b690
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   TEST                         0x0000000101c2a3f0 0x100098000 + 28910576
1   ???                           0x000000016fd39f48 0 + 6171107144
2   TEST                         0x0000000101f6f93c 0x100098000 + 32340284
3   MapKit                         0x0000000195f23888 -[MKMapView annotationManager:didSelectAnnotationRepresentation:] + 764
4   MapKit                         0x0000000195ee417c -[MKAnnotationManager selectAnnotation:animated:avoid:] + 720
5   MapKit                         0x0000000195f15cdc -[MKMapView _handleSelectionAtPoint:] + 552
6   UIKit                         0x000000018ff47c54 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 64
7   UIKit                         0x000000018ff4b488 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 124
8   UIKit                         0x000000018fb05540 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 252
9   UIKit                         0x000000018f9a745c -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 720
10  UIKit                         0x000000018ff3b72c _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 988
11  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001897f49a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
12  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001897f2628 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
13  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001897f2a74 __CFRunLoopRun + 956
14  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000189722d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
15  GraphicsServices               0x000000018b18c074 GSEventRunModal + 100
16  UIKit                         0x000000018f9db130 UIApplicationMain + 208
17  TEST                         0x0000000100ac54d8 0x100098000 + 10671320
18  libdyld.dylib                 0x000000018873159c start + 4
```

I've no idea what can happen here.
Any help would be appreciated.

My code works fine on XCode 8.2.1 and iOS 10.2.1 (but I can't downgrade...)

Regards,
Alex